# Cannot disable tslint rule via Codelyzer on Angular Template

Tags: angular, tslint, codelyzer

I have an Angular template that needs to call function by passing an index. There is a Codelyzer rule ["template-no-call-expression"](http://codelyzer.com/rules/template-no-call-expression/) that complains when I do this.

I have attempted to disable the rule in the typescript file, but it continues to fail the lint check. Is this a bug, or am I not doing it correctly?

```
/* tslint:disable: template-no-call-expression */
@Component({
...
```

Comment: you have this in the tslint json file right

Comment: No, it's in the component file... I don't want it disabled on the whole project.

Comment: Did you try after restarting your editor? It happened with me as well and after restarting the editor all works as expected.

Comment: The editor is not a factor, tslint runs on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the tslint-disabling is the FIRST line in your component.ts (so that means: above the imports)! I had the same problem and after reading the comment on the pull request below, I realized that if you put the disabling on line 17 of your TS, it will disable the check for all lines 17+ in your HTML file, but NOT for line 1 - 16 :\

See comment on https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/pull/492

Comment: I'm confused by your answer - you don't specify rules in the `component.ts` file

Comment: In your question, you put `/* tslint:disable: template-no-call-expression */` above your @Component in your TS file to disable the tslint check for your corresponding HTML right? The solution was to move the `/* tslint:disable: template-no-call-expression */` to the FIRST rule = line number of your TS file. Maybe my use of the word "rule" for both "line number" and "tslint rule" caused the confusion, sorry for that :)

Comment: OK, I'l give that a try.